# accessibility stylesheet switcher

Tags: jquery, insert, stylesheet, switch-statement, head

Ok, what I need to do is,

- toggle an accessibility stylesheet off and on
- set a cookie for 10 days
- check if the cookies is on an if it is add the stylesheet to the head.

I have it working with erratic behaviour.

```
$(document).ready(function() {      

     if( $.cookie('accessibility-visual') == "on" ) { 
                   $('head').append(' <link id rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/accessibility.css" />');  

      }       

      $('#visual').on('click', function(e){

      if( $.cookie('accessibility-visual') == "on" ) { 

          $.cookie("accessibility-visual", null);
          $(this).text("Off");
           $('link').attr('href', 'css/accessibility.css').remove(); 
           return false;

      }

      else {

           $.cookie("accessibility-visual", "on", { expires: 7 });
           $(this).text("On");
           $('head').append(' <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/accessibility.css" />');  

      }


      });   
});
```

Comment: $('link').attr('href', 'css/accessibility.css').remove(); sets the HREF of *all* of your stylesheets, then removes them. I don't think this is what you intend. Use an ID.

Comment: Instead of toggling a stylesheet link, why not toggle a class on <html> that adds you accessibility styles?